# Английские слова в русском языке

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Мне нужно написать такое предложение: "Таймлайн (идёт?) после окончания второго триместра..." Глагол 'идёт' здесь подойдёт или лучше просто поставить тире? Или сюда можно вставить какие-то другие глаголы? 
P.S.: таймлайн - временные рамки, ну, или линия времени, если уж дословно.

Comment: А что вы хотите сказать по-русски? Таймлайн - это ось времени с делениями и прочими отметками, ничего более.

Comment: Мне нужно узнать, можно ли в моём предложении употребить глагол 'идёт' на том месте, на котором я его написала. А если Вы говорите, что слово 'таймлайн' и вовсе здесь не подходит, то подскажите мне тогда, пожалуйста, синоним к словосочетанию "временные рамки".

Comment: По времени это планируется сразу после окончания...

Comment: Если нужно написать - пишите. Бумага стерпит всё.

Answer (score 1):

Такое предложение со словом «таймлайн» выглядит немного неуклюже (по крайней мере вне контекста).

Можно так:

```
|----------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------->
1 триместр             2 триместр                0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9         t

*время отсчитывается после окончания второго триместра.
```